# How to create a measure for distinct category value in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

category

A

B

C

A

C

B

C

A

B

A

I want only 4 Unique values Like Below

Category

A

B

C

Comment: Not 4 . In fact, 3 unique values -{A, B, C}

Answer (score 0):

You need a table function to do that:

```
Version - 1 = VALUES(Your_Table[category])
```

OR

```
Version - 2 = DISTINCT(Your_Table[category])
```

OR

```
Version - 3 = ALL(Your_Table[category])
```

OR

```
Version - 4 = SUMMARIZE(Your_Table,Your_Table[category] )
```